# Image Slider in Android using ViewPager

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development and I am trying to implement a simple Image Slider to view some images using ViewPager. I found this code in some website and am trying to install and run on both simulator and my android phone but after compiling and installing the app it does not open (in fact i kept getting the message 'app keeps stopping'). I am so new to android that I do not even know how to debug this. Can someone please help?
This is the error I am getting after making changes to the androidx and necessary gradle dependency as some people mentioned:

```
2019-09-05 11:02:05.645 2886-24531/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.test.imageslider/.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{668012 22868:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search/u0a58} (pid=22868, uid=10058) not exported from uid 10088
2019-09-05 11:02:05.649 22868-22868/? E/ContextIntentStarter: Cannot start activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.test.imageslider/.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.test.imageslider/.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{668012 22868:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search/u0a58} (pid=22868, uid=10058) not exported from uid 10088
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1701)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1654)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3564)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1526)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4403)
        at android.support.v4.app.w.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:132)
        at com.google.android.libraries.ac.c.b.a.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:54)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4362)
        at android.support.v4.app.w.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:129)
        at com.google.android.libraries.ac.c.b.a.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:51)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4686)
        at com.google.android.libraries.ac.c.b.a.startActivity(SourceFile:45)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.r.d.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.debug.b.b.a(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.r.a.a(SourceFile:19)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.r.b.a(SourceFile:8)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.shared.overlay.a.o.a(SourceFile:29)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.shared.service.w.a_(SourceFile:77)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.shared.service.ag.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ci.a(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ch.run(SourceFile:5)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

For some reason there is still a line for android.support.v4!

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test.imageslider;



import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.test.imageslider;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.imageslider" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.example.test.imageslider.MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.imageslider.MainActivity">



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Post your error log

Comment: I do not have any stacktrace in logcat after running on AVD

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology. How do I generate error log after running on AVD?

Comment: once app crashed it  gives  error in logcat..try to find that error log in logcat.Without error log not possible to help you out

Comment: Thank you! I added the error I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in you dependencies

```
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

And Remove

```
api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Replace

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
```

With

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewPager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="190dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

You have not write  Any entry point in you app please write it

```
  <activity 
    android:name="com.example.test.imageslider.MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Comment: thank you for this i will try changing this and perhaps capture logs too

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is here

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
```

because you are using `androidx` based libraries, thats why your app is crashing
Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager/widget/package-summary) link for more information based on `androidx viewpager`.
would be more easy to tell exact solution if you can provide logs, hope that helps.

Comment: I made this change and one other change to gradle file as per another answer and posted the logs.

Answer (score 0):

There is different set of libraries in `androidx`. normal `android.support.v4` based libraries cannot be supported. use this instead `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`